# angular redirect path to current page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to redirect any empty path to the current page which ie basically be on the current opened page. Is there a way I can achieve this through routing module? Thanks in advance for your help.

Here are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'students',
    component: StudentComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'teachers',
    component: TeacherComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '' // here I just want to redirect to the current page/do nothing
  }
];
```

Comment: May be I am wrong but I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a blank page, when the path is empty you redirect to that blank page, on the blank page you return to the previous page. Maybe that will help you.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common'

@Component({...})
export class BlankComponent {
  constructor(private location: Location) {
     this.location.back()
 }
}
```